# Call Super Constructor

Tags: scala

I have a custom exception class like the following :

```
case class CustomException(errorMsg:String)  extends Exception(error:String)
```

All what I need that when I catch exception is to throw my custom exception and pass my error message to the custom exception .
I expect from CustomException constructor to call super(errMsg)
However , this isn't what goes now and I got a compilation error .

```
 catch {
      case s: Exception => throw CustomException("This is a custom message")
    }
```

How could I call the super constructor :

```
super(errorMessage)
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
case class CustomException(errorMsg:String)  extends Exception(errorMsg)
```

Comment: Thx. However I am curious why Scala doesn't have super(errorMsg) as Java does !!

Comment: @Echo: Because it's not Java, and because a super constructor can *only* be called from a class's primary constructor, and even then - it can only be called as the very first operation in a constructor.  Scala's syntax better represents this underlying restriction (as imposed by the JVM)

Comment: What if you want both exception constructors (string,throwable) and (string) to be implemented in your custom exception?

Comment: Ok I kind of figured out a solution for this:

`class FrontendException(message: String, t: Throwable) extends RuntimeException(message, t) {
  def this(m: String) = this(m, null);
  def this(t: Throwable) = this(null, t)
}` but somehow something hurts when I use nulls in scala

Answer (score 7):

```
case class CustomException(errorMsg:String)  extends Exception(errorMsg)
```

You're calling the superclass's constructor, but the argument you are passing (`error`) isn't bound to anything.