# What is the use of open and close paren after Matcher[Int] in the case class below?

Tags: scala

```
case class beEven(b: Int) extends Matcher[Int]() {
  def apply(n: => Int) =  (n % 2 == 0, "%d is even".format(n), "%d is odd".format(n))
}
```

What is the use of open and close paren after Matcher[Int] in the case class below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about Scalatest's `org.scalatest.matchers.Matcher` **trait**, the seemingly incorrect parens can be attributed to the open scalac issue [SI-6805](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6805): "Compiler allows empty argument lists for traits".

Answer (score 0):

Empty parentheses usually can be omitted in Scala.

In your case empty parentheses represent the [empty argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6726810/1349366) list of the constructor of the `Matcher` class. In this case parentheses can be safely omitted.

The only case when empty parentheses make sense is [calling mutator method](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#arity-0). But it's only a convention, not a language syntax requirement.